# Committing to github with RStudio

Tags: git-config

I cannot **commit** to my github repository with Rstudio.

I followed the correct syntax and tutorial. This is the error I am getting:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DeE5.png]

Comment: Have you tried opening CMD and running those commands it lists?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to config a global user.

try to run the command:

```
git config --global user.email "[your email]"
```

```
git congif --global user.name "[your username]"
```